# Advanced look at HTTP headers

Tags: delphi, indy

Is it possible to read the HTTP headers (specifically the `GET` header) in the Indy `TIdHTTPServer.OnConnect` event without interfering with the subsequent `OnCommandGet` event?

If I try to pull them with a loop of `ReadLn`'s then `OnCommandGet` never fires. I need an advanced peek at them without pulling them from the input buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to read the HTTP headers (specifically the `GET` header) in the Indy `TIdHTTPServer.OnConnect` event without interfering with the subsequent `OnCommandGet` event?

It it *possible*, in that you could use the `TIdIOHandler.WaitFor()` method to wait for the header terminator to arrive in the `TIdIOHandler.InputBuffer`, returning everything received before it without removing anything from the buffer, eg:

```pascal
procedure TMyForm.IdHTTPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  headers: String;
begin
  header := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WaitFor(EOL+EOL, False);
  ...
end;
```

However, this has some limitations:

- it assumes each line is terminated by the byte sequence `$0D $0A` and thus the header is terminated by the byte sequence `$0D $0A $0D $0A`. This is technically true per the HTTP standards, and will *usually* be the case.  However, some clients *do* terminate lines with just `$0A` and thus the header would be terminated by `$0A $0A`.  `TIdHTTPServer` would normally handle that just fine, but using `WaitFor()` would not.

  A more robust solution would involve using `TIdIOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource()` in a loop, manually scanning the `TIdIOHandler.InputBuffer` until either `$0D $0A $0D $0A` or `$0A $0A` is found in the buffer.
- this won't work if there are multiple HTTP requests on the same connection, which can happen if HTTP keep-alives or HTTP pipelining are used.  You would be "peeking" the header of only the 1st HTTP request on the connection.

> If I try to pull them with a loop of `ReadLn`'s then `OnCommandGet` never fires.

Correct, because `TIdHTTPServer` expects to be the one to read them off the `InputBuffer`.  If you read them yourself beforehand, there won't be anything left for `TIdHTTPServer` to read, so it won't know what each HTTP request even looks like.

> I need an advanced peek at them without pulling them from the input buffer.

Why?  What do you want to do with them, if you could get them?

You should check if the `TIdHTTPServer.OnHeadersAvailable` event suits your needs.  It is fired at the beginning of every HTTP request, after the headers have been read from the `InputBuffer` but before the request body has been read.

Comment: The reason for doing this before CommandGet is because I have some connection management routines that limit connections made from one group of users (players) but not for another group (admins). I know which is which from the GET header. Since a single connection will spawn multiple CommandGets, I don't want to wait until then because I would have to insert tests to prevent logging the same connection multiple times. I'll do it if I have to but it would be simpler before then. I'll study your comments above and see if I can make that work. Thanks.

Comment: @kbriggs officially the http protool is stateless, so it doesn't have a 'connection' - the tcp layer needs to make a connection in order to exchange the http protocol data.  So it sems to me that if you want to use http as a transport you should respect the way http works and accept the tcp connection, and then respond to the GET command appropriately (possibly having to wait until you have all headers).

Comment: @kbriggs seems like something you can easily do with the `OnHeadersAvailable` event. You can store user data in `TIdContext` or `TIdHTTPSession`. On the first event of a new TCP connection, test what you need and store the result in the Context or HTTPSession. On subsequent events, if the result is already stored then skip your tests.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by peeking at the Inputbuffer per Remy's suggestion:

```
procedure TForm1.IdHTTPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  s: string;
  Done: boolean;
begin
  Done := False;
  repeat
    Sleep(10);
    if AContext.Connection.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource then
    begin
      s := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.AsString;
      if (Pos(#13#10#13#10, s) > 0) or (Pos(#10#10, s) > 0) then Done := True;
    end;
  until Done;
...
end;
```

One issue I could see happening is a bot making a TCP connection on my port and that loop never ending since no headers are coming. I would need to add some kind of timeout check.

The other suggestion of using OnHeadersAvailable wouldn't work for me because it's called right before OnCommandGet each time (i.e., multiple times per connection when KeepAlive is True) so I might as well just put tests in OnCommandGet if I went that route.

**EDIT:**

I also just tried doing this in the OnConnect handler:

```
s := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WaitFor(#10, False, True, nil, 1000);
```

Since I only need the GET line and it will always be first (right?) if it's included at all, I just need to find the first line feed character. That solves the line terminator problem and there's a timeout parameter that solves the bot issue. While this does read the first line header, it also causes an immediate disconnect and CommandGet never gets called. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FYI, I'm using Indy 10.6.2.5469